# get tow value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code for dropdown in edit form:

```
    <select id="inputState"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="seletRoleId"  formControlName="roleName">
      <option *ngFor="let item of roleList" seletRoleId="item.id" [value]="item.name"> {{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

But I need to get `item.name` and `item.id`.

This code `[value]="item.name"` for show user `RoleName` for edit.

How can I get tow value `id` and `name` from the dropdown?

Comment: Just bind the entire `item`instead?

Comment: @briosheje i need to bind `item.id` to `seletRoleId`

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a click so that each time an option is clicked it sends the item to a function. Then in the function you have access to the entire item.

```
<option *ngFor="let item of roleList" seletRoleId="item.id"
(click)=getDetails(item) [value]="item.name"> 
  {{item.name}}
 </option>
```

Then in your controller a function looking like so would allow you to do as you wish with the item. Store it as Component Variable or do the work you need in the function.

```
public currentSelection;

public getDetails(item): void
{
    this.currentSelection = item;

    console.log(item.id);
    console.log(item.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object instead, like that you can get the name and the id

```
<option ... [value]="{name: item.name, id: item.id} | json">
```

You can parse the result to get a proper object after.

Simple example

```js
changeConsole() {
  console.log(JSON.parse(this.selectRole).id);
  console.log(JSON.parse(this.selectRole).name);
}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectRole" (change)="changeConsole()">
  <option [value]="{name: 'toto', id: 11} | json"> yo 11
  </option>
  <option [value]="{name: 'titi', id: 13} | json"> yo 13
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @kianoush You can do the same thing with `seletRoleId="{name: item.name, id: item.id}"`

Comment: @kianoush your item is undefined ? You are speaking about `roleId` but I think you use `seletRoleId` as model in your code.

Comment: `seletRoleId ` in `number` type

Comment: i convert that to model but `id` is null

Comment: @kianoush Hum I forget some part, sorry. I update my answer, note I am not an expert with angular. There surly a best way to archive what you want. But with my answer you have the id and the name into the same model.

Comment: This code created a problem . in this code not pre-selected dropdown .